# Configuring a Virtual Procedure's result to never expire?

Tags: redhat-datavirt

How do I configure a Virtual Procedure's result to never expire in cache?  For example, how would I configure the ttl in this example so the cache never expires:

```
"/*+ cache(pref_mem ttl:70000) */
```

Answer (score 0):

add `/*+ cache */` to procedure definition.

See https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/TEIID/Results+Caching